# Application for trimming a video mp4 of ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: video

I would like to trim a video I have in mp4 format and I can't seem to find the right tool to do this. My laptop has Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Comment: What do you mean by "trim"? Remove some scenes (e.g. the first 30 seconds), or cut the view area (e.g. remove the top 50 pixels of the whole movie)?

Comment: I have a video of a movie and I want to make another video with only a small part of the first video. I don't know which tool to use

Comment: "small part of the first video" is still ambiguous IMHO. It could be a small time sequence, or a small screen area.

Answer (score 14):

You need to install `ffmpeg`.

To install the ffmpeg `sudo apt-get install ffmpeg` to copy specific short durationg from the video file.

Sample :-

```
ffmpeg -i original.mp4 -ss 00:03:20 -c copy -t 00:00:30 output.mp4
```

-i  -->Input file. The file name of the original video clip.

-ss -->Copy the new video from the original video started after 
       3 minute and 20 seconds.

-t  -->Duration of the new video clip,(ex:- 30 seconds.)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can you please explain how do I get the ffmpeg?

Comment: You need to run sudo apt-get install ffmpeg command

Comment: This is great for other Ubuntu versions as well and it's beneficial that you can do it from command line

Comment: I tried using this code exactly (just with different start time and length) but my output.mp4 was only the audio track. I also tried output.avi but got the same result. Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong? I'm on 20.04

Comment: UPDATE: I needed to change the order of the arguments. For me, I used `ffmpeg -ss 00:01:57 -i input.mp4 -t 00:51:05 -c copy output.mp4`. I don't have an explanation for why it worked this way but not as posted by @ErandaPeiris

Answer (score 3):

Vidcutter is a simple tool that can trim your videos. Install with

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ozmartian/apps
sudo apt update
sudo apt install vidcutter
```

Lauch vidcutter and select a file with the open button:

[image]

use the vertical bar to scroll to the first part to add to the video and click

start split.
Drag the bar to where you want the video to end and click end clip. Then use the save button to join your videos. There is no loss in quality in the process

Comment: happy to assist.

Answer (score 2):

You could checkout  my project called **VideoCut**.

It has a very fast muxer (you can cut without recoding). Its design has been kept simple and was inspired by DVB-Cut.

It supports mp4, AVCH ,avi, webm and supports TS transportstreams

[image: Main Screen]

and can be downloaded from [github](https://github.com/kanehekili/VideoCut).

Answer (score 0):

You can use my app [dmMediaConverter](http://dmsimpleapps.blogspot.ro/2014/04/dmmediaconverter.html) for this. It has an option to trim the file without reencoding it, so, it is very **fast** and **lossless**.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Avidemux is one of open-source GUI application doesn't need to install via PPA.  Quite easy to comprehend, self-explained.
  To install avidemux

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install avidemux2.6-qt
```

[image: avidemux sample]

To remove it

```
sudo apt-get remove --autoremove avidemux2.6-qt
```